# tic doesn't read from STDIN and segfaults when adding terminfo to support italics in tmux

Tags: macos, command-line, tmux

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/2.2/FAQ#L355-L378) to add italics support to tmux.

**1)** I tried running copying-pasting and running this command

```
cat <<EOF|tic -x -
    tmux|tmux terminal multiplexer,
        ritm=\E[23m, rmso=\E[27m, sitm=\E[3m, smso=\E[7m, Ms@,
        use=xterm+tmux, use=screen,

    tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors,
        use=xterm+256setaf, use=tmux,
```

but that gives me:

```
tic: Can't open -
```

I'm guessing this is because OS X's `tic` doesn't support reading from `stdin`.

**2)** I then tried saving the terminfo to a temporary file named `tmux.terminfo` and ran it using `tic -x tmux.terminfo`

```
tmux|tmux terminal multiplexer,
    ritm=\E[23m, rmso=\E[27m, sitm=\E[3m, smso=\E[7m, Ms@,
    use=xterm+tmux, use=screen,

tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors,
    use=xterm+256setaf, use=tmux,
```

However, I get this error message

```
[1]    32091 segmentation fault  tic -x tmux.terminfo
```

**3)** I also tried running `tic` without the `-x` flag, so that it doesn't treat unknown capabilities as user-defined.

That gives me this:

```
"tmux.terminfo", line 2, col 62, terminal 'tmux': unknown capability 'Ms'
[1]    35607 segmentation fault  tic tmux.terminfo
```

I'm on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: You're right, OS X's `tic` doesn't read from stdin. `tic` is looking for definitions for `xterm+tmux` and `xterm+256setaf`, and it can't find them, so it segfaults (unfortunately). You could try a newer [terminfo.src](http://invisible-island.net/datafiles/current/terminfo.src.gz) which includes these. `mkdir ~/.terminfo; gunzip terminfo.src.gz; export TERMINFO=~/.terminfo; tic -x -e tmux terminfo.src; tic -x -e tmux-256color terminfo.src`.Having said all that, I'm not sure if italics are supported in Terminal/iTerm2...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this works for me, notice I edited `use` like @mtklr suggested:

```
# A screen-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
# run to add to term db: tic tmux.terminfo
tmux|tmux terminal multiplexer,
  ritm=\E[23m, rmso=\E[27m, sitm=\E[3m, smso=\E[7m, Ms@,
  use=xterm, use=screen,

tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors,
  use=xterm-256color, use=tmux,
```

Then `tic -x tmux.terminfo`

Shouldn't have errors

Then added to .tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -as terminal-overrides ',xterm*:sitm=\E[3m'
```

Comment: use=xterm and use=xterm-256color have undesirable side effects since it changes all the keys around. The definitions of xterm+256setaf and xterm+tmux are like one line, it'd be better to just include them. And that wasn't even what @mtklr suggested.

Comment: this one also worked for me with iTerm2, tmux (both with native iTerm2 integration and without) and Neovim.

Answer (score 4):

The above solution didn't work for me, however, this did:

## 1. Create two files:

File `xterm-256color-italic.terminfo`:

```
# A xterm-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
xterm-256color-italic|xterm with 256 colors and italic,
  sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
  use=xterm-256color,
```

File `tmux-256color-italic.terminfo`:

```
# A xterm-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
tmux-256color-italic|tmux with 256 colors and italic,
  sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
  use=xterm-256color,
```

## 2. tic them both

```
tic xterm-256color-italic.terminfo
tic tmux-256color-italic.terminfo
```

## 3. Tell your terminal to use xterm and tmux to use tmux with overrides.

Figure out how to set your terminals $TERM variable to `xterm-256color-italic`. In iTerm it's in Prefs -> profiles -> Terminal -> Report Terminal Type.

In your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
# tmux display in 256 colours
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color-italic"
#  enable terminal compatibility with outside terminal
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color-italic:Tc"
```

## 4. Test for *italics* and colour

```
# Test Italics
echo `tput sitm`italics`tput ritm`
# Test Colour (should be smooth gradient)
awk 'BEGIN{
    s="/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\"; s=s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s;
    for (colnum = 0; colnum<256; colnum++) {
        r = 255-(colnum*255/255);
        g = (colnum*510/255);
        b = (colnum*255/255);
        if (g>255) g = 510-g;
        printf "\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", r,g,b;
        printf "\033[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", 255-r,255-g,255-b;
        printf "%s\033[0m", substr(s,colnum+1,1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}'
```

If I understand correctly tmux depends on an external terminal environment in order to render text correctly. This means it needs to translate/override certain commands.

source: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/696